# Seeking SF story read in 1990s about teenage Lunar colonist boy visiting undersea aqua farming colony.

Tags: story-identification

I have put some additional details below, but as a quick note this is not Deep Range by Arthur C. Clark. However, it not only shares many of the same types of undersea aqua culture/farming with Deep Range, as I recall the story had a 'Clarkesian' feel to it. Unfortunately reviewing Clarke's bibliograpy and having read most of the novels/novellas lsited I could not find one that fit. That includes Cradle which also has some aquatic themes. Nor is it Dolphin Island, The Hydronauts nor any of the Tom Swift stories. I am pretty sure it was at least novella length if not a full novel.

A teenage Lunar colonist boy visits Earth with his diplomat father during a bid for Lunar independence. In one memorable early scene at the hotel/resort/ambassadorial complex at which they are staying he is at the pool (which he does frequently because it helps relieve the gravity pull which is hard for him).  He watches with some minor disbelieve at the practice of tourists putting oil on themselves and baking in the sun.  However, he then notices a teenage girl who is as pale as a moonbeam and can swim with the ease and grace of porpoise. The girl turns out to be an aqua farming colonist whose parent is also at the (UN?) gathering to consider the Lunar independence proposal.

The two hit it off and the boy is allowed to go with the girl to her undersea home. In one early scene within the undersea colony dome the boy is scared when he finds cannot speak without squeaking. It was an oxy-helium mix (vs. nitrogen) used to prevent the bends (a later plot point). The undersea colonists allow the boy to help with various tasks around the colony. He gets stung by I believe either a manta ray or jellyfish which becomes a plot point later on.  At one point there is what appears to be sabotage to the 'fish fence' which shuts off the walls of bubbles in the water keeping the fish penned in. The boy is accused of being the saboteur and is put on trial. In an interesting judicial form defendants and witnesses are asked to swear in using either a globe or a silver/platinum orb representing the moon. Towards the end of the book there is a climactic escape scene during the voting on the Lunar independence. The boy does an untimed ascent out of the colony (leading to the bends mentioned earlier).

While the age of the protagonists (older teens) and lack of overt sex/violence made it feel like a young adult story I don't think it was meant as one. But, could be wrong.

Comment: Yep.  That;s the one.  Crisis on Conshelf Ten.  Thanks for the quick ID.

Comment: no problem, I remembered it because I asked the same question myself a few months ago, glad to help